# Refer to hintbases in Ltac

Tags: coq, coq-tactic

In my project, I am attempting to maintain small hintbases in order to speed up proofs. However, when I am writing Ltac support for such architecture, I couldn't find a way to refer to the various hintbases. Essentially, I want to do the following:

```
Tactic Notation "myauto" ???(db) := auto with db.
```

It will be more complicated than that. However, Coq parser seems eagerly parse `db` to be the concrete name of the hint base, and therefore error message like this will be thrown:

```
Error: No such Hint database: db.
```

Any way I can parameterize the hint base option for `auto` family?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

EDIT:

What you are trying to do is currently not working in Ltac.

https://github.com/coq/coq/issues/2417

You can get around your issue by either

- rephrasing your issue into a separate question where you give some explanation why you need this kind of automation, where someone might be able to help you solving the initial problem in a different way (not using auto and database parameters)

or

- trying out one of the newer Coq tactic libraries, like [Ltac2](https://github.com/ppedrot/ltac2)

---

Old (broken) answer:

In Coq 8.7.2 what you are looking for is the `ident` argument type.
According to the definition, a Hint database is referenced by an `ident`:

```
Create HintDb ident [discriminated]
```

(see https://coq.inria.fr/distrib/current/refman/tactics.html#Hints-databases for the definition)

Putting

```
Tactic Notation "test" ident(db) :=
  auto with db.
```

works fine for me.

https://coq.inria.fr/distrib/current/refman/syntax-extensions.html#hevea_command236 contains a list of allowed modifiers.

Comment: The last link is broken.

Comment: Thanks for noticing. I have repaired it.

Comment: i've read through the whole refman before asking here. I am using coq 8.6 and it does not work there for any argument type, including `hintbases` and `ne_preident_list` which are not listed at all.

Comment: Can you please update your question stating that you need a solution for 8.6 and what error you get for my suggestion? The current latest version is 8.7.2, with which I have tested the above.

Comment: @HuStmpHrrr You are indeed right. I just tested with Coq 8.6 and writining `test core` will not work for my solution. Looking into this a bit showed me, that while it may look like it captures the defined db parameter, it does not.

Comment: @HuStmpHrrr I am sorry. I just checked and it is currently not possible to implement what you are asking for. I have updated my answer accordingly.

Comment: @nesreka ok i see. thx. it's hard to always migrate to the latest version of any software, due to lack of immediate support of external dependencies. at least it's a good news that some later version of coq would work.

Comment: @HuStmpHrrr this will not work in Coq 8.7.2 either. If you really need exactly this tactic you will have to resort to the second part of my updated answer, using one of the newer tactics libraries.